# What is the program flow in case navigation based application developed for iphone in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationcontroller

I want to know the sequence in which default or predefined methods ( such as viewDidLoad applicationDidFinishLaunching etc) are called in program execution in a navigation based application.

Answer (score 1):

See a life cycle for a view controller

1. init
2. loadView (if view wasn't specified with initWithNibName)
3. viewDidLoad
4. viewWillAppear
5. viewDidAppear
6. //here come some actions
7. viewWillDisappear
8. viewDidDisappear
9. viewDidUnload (in case of memory warnings)

Everything else depends on the sequence and methods (IB or through code) of instantiating of root view controllers.

Comment: where in this sequence, applicationDidFinishLaunching or applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions are executed? Also what will happen if I implement both the methods?

Comment: note that `viewDidUnload` won't always be called. It will be called in case the view is destroyed before the view controller (for example if the navigation controller gets a memory warning), but it won't be called when the view controller itself is dealloc'ed (for example if you tap back on your navigation controller, the view controller will get `viewDidDisappear` -> `dealloc`, no `viewDidUnload`).